# How can I extract the background color of a table cell within a PDF file using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, tablecell, tabula-py

I've been using tabula-py, PyPDF2 and tika modules, but none of them seems to detect the background color of a table cell, which is within a PDF file.

These colored cells mean important information in the context of my problem. I know, for exemple, that tabula-py is a wrapper from tabula-java and this one does not provided colored cell information. Is there some easy-to-follow solution in Python out there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer: I am the author of the library `borb` used in this answer

**about PDF**: PDF is not so much a "what you see is what you get" format, as it is a container for rendering instructions. That means a table is in fact just a collection of rendering instructions that draws something we humans interpret as a table. Something like:

- go to location x, y
- set the current stroke colour to black
- set the current fill colour to blue
- set the font to Helvetica, size 12
- draw a line to x, y
- move the pen up
- go to x, y
- render the string "Hello World"

Whenever a PDF library is extracting tables from a PDF, it's important to keep in mind this is a heuristic. It's based on some assumptions. Such as "tables tend to have a large number of lines that intersect at 90-degree angles".

I suggest you have a look at `TableDetectionByLines` in `borb`. It's a class that gathers the aforementioned rendering instructions and spits out the locations of tables in the PDF document.

You would use it as such:

```py
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.table.table import Table, TableCell
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.table.table_detection_by_lines import TableDetectionByLines

doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
with open(input_file, "rb") as input_pdf_handle:
    l: TableDetectionByLines = TableDetectionByLines()
    doc = PDF.loads(input_pdf_handle, [l])

assert doc is not None
tables: typing.List[Table] = l.get_tables_for_page(0)
```

As it stands, this class does not track the stroke/fill colour. But you can easily subclass it, and modify it so it does.

For this, I would start at [this particular line](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb/blob/f426f54f1b42e673ecb34a5c3c7ba2c28a505f9b/borb/toolkit/table/table_detection_by_lines.py#L83).

Answer (score 1):

Some kind user reported my previous solution did not work well.
It's true because pdfplumber's `page.rects` does not always detect cells in table correctly.
Sometimes it only detects lines, rows, cols.
So I propose another solution here.

```py
import pdfplumber
from collections import Counter
    

def get_cell_color(image, cell:tuple[int, int, int, int]):
    cropped_image = image.crop(cell)
    pixels = list(cropped_image.convert('RGB').getdata())
    color_counts = Counter(pixels)
    most_common = color_counts.most_common(1)
    return most_common[0][0]


def demo(page):
    """example method: print colored cells information"""
    page_image = page.to_image().original
    tables = page.find_tables()
    
    for table in tables:
        extracted_table = table.extract()
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            for cell_idx, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
                cell_color = get_cell_color(page_image, cell)
                if cell_color != (255, 255, 255):
                    print(f"cell color: {cell_color}")
                    print(f"cell location: {cell}")
                    print(f"cell content: {extracted_table[row_idx][cell_idx]}")


pdf = pdfplumber.open("/path/to/target.pdf")
page = pdf.pages[0]
demo(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber).
Here is rough sample code.

```
from typing import Optional

import pdfplumber
from pdfplumber.page import Page, Table


def cmyk_to_rgb(cmyk: tuple[float, float, float, float]):
    r = 255 * (1.0 - (cmyk[0] + cmyk[3]))
    g = 255 * (1.0 - (cmyk[1] + cmyk[3]))
    b = 255 * (1.0 - (cmyk[2] + cmyk[3]))
    return r, g, b


def to_bbox(rect: dict) -> tuple[float, float, float, float]:
    return (rect["x0"], rect["top"], rect["x1"], rect["bottom"])


def is_included(cell_box: tuple[float, float, float, float], rect_box: tuple[float, float, float, float]):
    c_left, c_top, c_right, c_bottom = cell_box
    r_left, r_top, r_right, r_bottom = rect_box
    return c_left >= r_left and c_top >= r_top and c_right <= r_right and c_bottom <= r_bottom


def find_rect_for_cell(cell: tuple[float, float, float, float], rects: list[dict]) -> Optional[dict]:
    return next((r for r in rects if is_included(cell, to_bbox(r))), None)


def get_cell_color(cell: tuple[float, float, float, float], page: Page) -> tuple[float, float, float]:
    rect = find_rect_for_cell(cell, page.rects) if cell else None
    return cmyk_to_rgb(rect["non_stroking_color"]) if rect else (255, 255, 255)


pdf = pdfplumber.open("/path/to/target.pdf")
page = pdf.pages[0]
tables: list[Table] = page.find_tables()

# get RGB color of first(= top-left) cell of first table
print(get_cell_color(tables[0].rows[0].cells[0], page)) # => (r, g, b)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I can't tell you how enormously helpful it was. For anyone else in my situation, the rects didn't line up with the cells exactly and weren't consistent, but they were close. I used `math.isclose()` function from the `import math` Python library to find boxes and it worked like a charm. Here is the code I modified from the return statement on `is_included` function in this answer:

```return math.isclose(c_left, r_left, abs_tol=1) and math.isclose(c_top, r_top, abs_tol=1) and math.isclose(c_right, r_right, abs_tol=1) and math.isclose(c_bottom, r_bottom, abs_tol=1)```

Comment: @jrue wow it's cool! 
I should have checked and used such nice utilities. 
I am so happy to hear my solution was helpful.
Maybe my another solution is also interesting to you.